# Homology of $S^2\times I$ by Glueing two ends by degree $d$ map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to calculate singular homology of $S^2\times I$ by glueing two ends by a map $S^2\rightarrow S^2$ of degree $d$. My idea is to use Mayer-Vietoris, but I am not sure aboutt the open sets I should take. Should I take the open sets $A,B$ to be the two $S^2$ plus a bit to the right and to the left respectively to get the cylinder? If I do this, I have $H_2(A)\cong H_2(B)\cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$(I am not sure whether this is correct) and $H_1(A)=H_1(B)=0, H_0(A)=H_0(B)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. By Mayer-Vietoris, I got exact sequence
\begin{align*}
0\rightarrow H_3(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_2(X)\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_1(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}
\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: Your idea is one of the possibilities. Probably everything you try that is somewhat sensible should work.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I got $H_0(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}, H_1(X)\cong 0, H_2(X)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/d)^2, H_3(X)\cong(\mathbb{Z})^2$. Is it correct?

Comment: ^^ I made a mistake. $H_3(X)\cong\Bbb Z$ if $d=1$ but $H_3(X)=0$ for $d\neq 1$, I am almost sure. Also $H_1(X)\cong\Bbb Z$ I think. So, let's try that again: $$H_\ast(X)\cong\begin{cases}\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z,0,0,0,\cdots&d=1\\\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z/(d-1)\Bbb Z,0,0,0,\cdots&d\neq1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Deleting my mistaken older comment, I will repeat the main message: please edit your question to include your workings. This helps you, future readers and future answerers. You can't get help if no one can see why you're confused or what you're doing wrong... and your post doesn't benefit people who are trying to learn from your question, unless they can read your mind through the screen, if it doesn't contain much more than the problem statement.

Comment: If by $A,B$ being $S^2$ plus a bit to the left and right respectively, say, $A\sim S^2\times[0,\delta)$ and$B\sim S^2\times(1-\delta,1]$ then (i) these are not open (ii) these do not cover. Also, each of $A,B$ are homotopy equivalent to $S^2$ so $\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z$ is certainly not their homology. I think your approach is a bit unclear. Also, it is often important to (rigorously) determine what the maps actually are in the Mayer Vietoris sequence unless you are very lucky

Comment: @FShrike do you have suggestion how to approach this problem?

Comment: It's not easy to answer when there's not much to work with in the question, sorry. Some hints: you can work it out with Mayer Vietoris or - if you're careful! - with cellular homology (assuming my methods are right, that is, but I take confidence in the fact I got the same answer two different ways). A standard trick is to decompose the cylinder $X\times I$ into open halves, say, $X\times[0,\frac{2}{3})$ and $X\times(\frac{1}{3},1]$, and then apply the quotient map to get a decomposition of $Y=X\times I/\sim$ into open sets. It is manageable, to understand this decomposition and handle M-V

Comment: @FShrike Ok thank you.